# Javascript - how to iterate an object of array and remove duplicate IDs

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and continue learning.
I have an below array object which has duplicate ids in it. I want to iterate and create new array which contains only unique id's

const testobj =  {"100": [295, 681, 15220], "257": [295, 681, 1123]}

So the final output I am looking for
const ids = [295, 681,15220, 1123]

I know this is simple but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Pravin The duplicate question doesn't _exactly_ answer your question, but it should be helpful enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const testobj = {"100": [295, 681, 15220], "257": [295, 681, 1123]};

let merged = [].concat(...Object.values(testobj)); 
const ids = [...new Set(merged)];

console.log(ids);  // [295, 681, 15220, 1123]
```

You can achieve this by iterating over the values of the testobj object, merging them, and then creating a Set to filter out duplicates. Finally, you can convert the Set back into an array.

```
const testobj = {"100": [295, 681, 15220], "257": [295, 681, 1123]};

let merged = [].concat(...Object.values(testobj)); 
const ids = [...new Set(merged)];

console.log(ids);  // [295, 681, 15220, 1123]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

First extract all the arrays of IDs using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), then flatten these arrays into a single array using `[].`[`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). Next [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is used to remove the duplicate IDs. Finally `[...]` (using [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) is used to convert the Set back into an array.

```js
const testobj = {"100": [295, 681, 15220], "257": [295, 681, 1123]};
const uniqueIds = [...new Set([].concat(...Object.values(testobj)))];
console.log(uniqueIds);
```